# Android Dropbox Core API implementation

Tags: android, dropbox

I am trying to  implement the CORE API at my Android application.

I am following the Dropbox tutorial for this.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android

```
final static private String APP_KEY = "INSERT_APP_KEY";
final static private String APP_SECRET = "INSERT_APP_SECRET";

// In the class declaration section:
private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;

// And later in some initialization function:
AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
```

But, i don't know where to put this line of code?

```
mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MyActivity.this);
```

When i put it within the Oncreate() function i get a endless loop of authenticating the account with the  Dropbox App.

Can someone please show me a robust sample of code which is functional?

I also want to know how to read files from Dropbox via Dropbox CORE API?

Should i download first the file, save it to the mobile memory and then access it just like a  local file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android)

> We'll start by calling the startOAuth2Authentication() method which
>   will ask the user to authorize your app. If the Dropbox app is
>   installed, the SDK will switch to it so the user doesn't have to sign
>   in, and it will fallback to the browser if not.

Meaning you must have this method called when you are ready to initiate a transaction with the `Dropbox`'s servers. It seems like this method is checking for Dropbox's existance on the phone first and authenticates the user and if not found sends him to the web page to log in. So it sounds like this method fires up a special intent for the Dropbox app or the device's browser to handle, thus making it **not suitable** for placing it in the onCreate() method. This method should be placed right before you initiate a transaction with the server. (eg. a readFile() method that will be called once by a button's click.

From scanning through the official documentation it seems that in order to read a file you have to first **download** the file, save it as a cache (**temporary**) file, read it and when you're done **remove** it.

Comment: Well, yeah. You have right. I wanted to base my code on a single/simple sample of reading a file since i am having difficulties rightly implementing the library.

Comment: Yep, it helped me a lot. But i am struggling to find a simple example of how to download a dropbox file. The reading part from the cache is not a problem though. If you just can show me a simple example i would really appreciate your help.

Comment: The Datastore API seems to be the way of performing CRUD operations on the user's private database. Check out the **Quering Records** section on how to fetch results from a query: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/android

Scanning through the whole tutorial seems like a good idea that will help you use the `Dropbox's API securely and efficiently.

Comment: GeorgeD, thanks. I knew about Datastore API. But i am stuck with the CORE API. How to download a file and then read the content of the file. That's what i have been looking for.

Comment: Did you check the **Downloading Files** section of https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android ?

Comment: Yeah, George.  I checked  it. Tried to  download but  no  success.

Comment: What is the output of your stack trace when you try it? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No,  i don't get anything.  I am using  this code File file = new File("/magnum-opus.txt");
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
DropboxFileInfo info = mDBApi.getFile("/magnum-opus.txt", null, outputStream, null);
Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The file's rev is: " + info.getMetadata().rev);

Comment: No,  i don't get anything.  I am using  this code                                        File file = new File("/magnum-opus.txt");
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
DropboxFileInfo info = mDBApi.getFile("/magnum-opus.txt", null, outputStream, null);
Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The file's rev is: " + info.getMetadata().rev);                     And then  the Inputstream  command to read the  file from  the local-downloaded file. But nothing happens.

Comment: Please ommit the `/` from the new File("") and try again

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /userandpass.php: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
            at com.example.sssssss.LoginActivity.doDropboxTest(LoginActivity.java:102)  i get this error

Comment: `(Read-only file system)` it seems that you can not save the file at the location that you try to. Try a different location or use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int). (openFileOutput() method)

Comment: Well, apparently that's what the problem is. I am trying to find to save the dropbox file to a cache file.

Comment: Now i am getting this error  at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.getFileStream(DropboxAPI.java:1533)
            at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.getFile(DropboxAPI.java:1497)
            at com.example.kanun.worldontv.LoginActivity.doDropboxTest hmmmm.

Comment: I am sorry but we've strayed far from the original question. I can only help you up to a certain point from which you must move on by yourself.